# How to clean up logs printed by spring , i am using logback.xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I am new to spring boot.I want to remove below logs by spring framework, which is printing by default when ever my spring boot application shutdown.

I am using logback.xml for logging.

```
2018-07-02 21:56:11.623 [main] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@14514713: startup date [Mon Jul 02 21:55:43 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-02 21:56:11.624 [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

I tried by putting below entry in logback.xml file but it didn't work.

```
<logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="off" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
```

Comment: What do you mean by clean up?As you can set max file size ,you can enable logging at various level "debug","info","warn" as per your requirement .What is your motive to do so ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable log for all Spring classes use the following.

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="off"/>
```

You don't need to mention `appender-ref` since it won't be printed.